# Interpolate over specified axis in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, interpolation, resampling, gridding

I have an n-dimensional matrix, `funtointerpolate`, and I wish to perform one dimensional interpolation along one of its axes (let's call it axis `m`). In Python, interpolate functions such as `interp1d` allow one to specify the axis of interpolation. In MATLAB, I cannot see an obvious way to do this using `interp1` or any other built-in interpolate functions. Ideally, the function would look something like

```
interpolatedfun = interp1(funtointerpolate,oldpoints,newpoints,axis = m)
```

An obvious way to get around this is to loop over all the other axes in `funtointerpolate`, but this is rather cumbersome. The motivation for interpolation is that the data in `funtointerpolate` is evaluated along a non-uniform grid along the `m` axis. I need it to be uniform along `m`. Mathematically, suppose I have some tensorial object

```
A_{ijk}
```

which is evaluated along a non-uniform grid along the j index. Then, I wish to find a new `A` such that the jth index consists of values evaluated on a uniform grid. I know the new uniform grid for the jth index, `newpoints`, and the old grid `oldpoints`.

Comment: [`interpn(oldAx1,...,oldAxM,...,oldAxN, oldAx1,...,newAxM,...,oldAxN)`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interpn.html)?

Comment: Wait a second... What exactly do you mean, mathematically or geometrically, by interpolating a vector along an axis? Since the only data you have for each dimension is one value, interpolation (or extrapolation) would just return the same value, no? Would you please show what you mean using a small example with e.g. 3 or 4 dimensions?

Comment: The functionality would be analogous to the `dim` argument one can pass in fft:https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html

Comment: I'm very curious how you intend to perform `fft` on a single data point (because `size(funtointerpolate, anyDim) == 1)`). Perhaps you meant to write "n dimensional **matrix**" and not "n dimensional **vector**".

Comment: @Dev-iL Ah yes, that is certainly a typo! Editing now.

Comment: Ok, great! So what about my initial suggestion, does that not work for you?(`interpn` or `griddatan`)?

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`interpn`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interpn.html) function for this purpose:

```
newV = interpn(oldAx1, ..., oldAxM, ..., oldAxN, oldV, ...
               oldAx1, ..., newAxM, ..., oldAxN);
```

where `V` is your output.

(Of course the above is pseudo-code, but it should nicely illustrate the way to solve your problem.)